# В чем разница текста в скобках и элемента массива?

Tags: javascript, html

Скрипт перебирает массив, берет ключ - находит select такого же класса и выбирает option с таким же текстом как и у элемента массива под тем ключом:

```
$('.vozv25 option').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).html() == array['vozv25']; 
}).prop('selected', 'true');
```

вот пример выше. Если ввести .html() = 'текст' вручную - работает, подставляет, а вот подставляю переменную - никак. Проверил, в переменной находиться точно тот код который нужен, ошибок нет.

Comment: `.html() = 'текст'` или `.html() == 'текст'`?

Comment: "ошибок нет" - джентльменам верят на слово? Ну, если ошибок нет, значит все работает.

Comment: @Igor имею ввиду ошибок в консоли)) + Другие такие же селекты работают нормально

Comment: @shumik_UA Посмотрите на код в моем ответе - имеет смысле добавить такой же `console.log` в Ваш код, чтобы выяснить, какие строки сравниваются в условии фильтра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время выполнения этого кода, в `array['vozv25']` не то значение, на которое Вы рассчитываете:

```
$('.vozv25 option').filter(function () { 
    console.log($(this).html(), array['vozv25'], $(this).html() == array['vozv25']);
    return $(this).html() == array['vozv25']; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```js
var array = { vozv25: "Test Three" };
//$('.vozv25 option').prop('selected', false);
$('.vozv25 option').filter(function() {
  console.log('['+$(this).html()+']', '['+array['vozv25']+']', $(this).html() == array['vozv25']);
  return $(this).html() == array['vozv25'];
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="vozv25">
  <option>Test One</option>
  <option selected>Test Two</option>
  <option>Test Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Но если я например ставлю alert(array['vozv13']) то выводит все правильно, + все остальные селекты работают правильно по тому же принципу

Comment: строки сравниваются правильно, снова таки проверил через alert - функция перебирает все варианты, в том числе и нужный, но не реагирует на него

Comment: @shumik_UA При чем здесь `'vozv13'`, если в коде речь идет о `'vozv25'`?

Comment: @shumik_UA Я зне знаю, как Вы проверили. Что вывелось в консоль браузера, после того, как Вы добавили `console.log` как у меня?

Comment: [6.6.1 FL*EVA*CG Premium T+] [6.6.1 FL*EVA*CG Premium T ] false спасибо.. вот в чем проблема. Сейчас буду думать что не так. Переменная передается через GET запрос, потом из него делаю массив js. + какой то спецсимвол? знаете как его замаскировать?

Comment: @shumik_UA Мало данных. Надо знать откуда берется текст для элементов `option`, а откуда данные в `array`. Попробуйте `$(this).text()` вместо `$(this).html()`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82888/discussion-between-shumik-ua-and-igor).